# Code Blocks 10.05 and 12.11, 13.12 returns different results with same code

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I wrote the code below to find if a number is palindrome or not. But when I compile and run the code, it returns different results in Code Blocks 10.05 and 12.11, 13.12.

I tried the code with the number 12321. Code Blocks 10.05 returns "The number 12321 has 5 digits and is a palindrome number". Code Blocks 12.11 and 13.12 returns "The number 12321 has 5 digits and is NOT a palindrome number".

Here is the code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int num, tmp, tmp2, i, k, last_num=0, check_num;

    cout<<"Enter a number : ";
    cin>>num;

    tmp=num;
    check_num=num;

    for(i=1; tmp>=10; ++i)
    {
        tmp=(tmp-(tmp%10))/10;
    }

    cout<<"The number "<<num<<" has "<<i<< " digits ";
    for(k=i-1; k>=0; k--)
    {
        tmp2 = num%10;
        last_num+=tmp2*pow(10,k);

        num=(num-(num%10))/10;
    }

    if(check_num == last_num)
    {
        cout<<"and is a palindrome number"<<endl<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"and is NOT a palindrome number"<<endl<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Smells like undefined behavior. I don't see that you tried to examine your code in a debugger, though. Also, using `pow()` to calculate integer powers is **wrong,** because the values returned by that function are not exact.

Comment: Hey look, a new version of CodeBlocks. Anyway, it would be the differences in GCC 4.4.1, GCC 4.7.(umm)1? and whatever the new version uses unless you changed any of them.

Comment: Adding to what H2CO3 said, you calculate `pow(10,-1)` at some point. Then you multiply it by something and cast the result to an int. Different rounding may occur for different compiler versions.

Comment: @Floris No, it would most probably not be faster, and **certainly not cleaner.** This is a **math problem** for which no strings are to be used. The best solution I can think of is building up the number in the reverse order using modulo arithmetic (`int k = 0; while (n) { k *= 10; k += n % 10; n /= 10; }`), then checking if the newly obtained number matches the original one.

Comment: You have published some observations. What is your *question*?

Comment: there is simple test. print those values and see. Plus as people noted your solution is really too complex for this small  task

Comment: @H2CO3 - what makes you say this is a **math problem**? It is only a math problem if you choose to treat it as such. I pointed out that the problem as stated could more easily be solved using existing string routines. The data is initially entered as a string - if you just kept it as a string the amount of manipulation would be minimized. I usually agree with you - but this time I don't. Your modulo trick is neat; but string reversal would be faster.

Comment: @Floris Let's benchmark it then. Memory access is generally slower than arithmetic, so I doubt string reversal would be faster.

Comment: @H2CO3 see code I posted below. I think the benchmark is fairly convincing. Look forward to your comments.

Comment: @Floris Thanks, interesting. It seems that division (be it regular or modulo) *is* slower than reading from memory. I'm quite in a hurry right now so I don't have the time to examine the assembly, but I'm sure that would explain it. Also, I'd be interested as to what would be different if the conversion took place in binary, octal or hexadecimal (just so that the arithmetic operations could be optimized to bitwise operations). While faster on your particular implementation, using strings does not become "The Right Solution (TM)", however -- the fact that we have a math problem didn't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is overly, unnecessarily complex and also incorrect (because of the problem with floating-point numbers I already mentioned, namely that the values returned by `pow()` may not be exact).

You can implement this in a much, much simpler an cleaner way: build the number up from its digits in the reverse order, then check if the number obtained this way matches the original:

```
int ispal(unsigned long long n)
{
    unsigned long o = n;
    unsigned long long k = 0;
    while (n) {
        k *= 10;
        k += n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }

    return o == k;
}
```

(`unsigned long long` is only used instead of plain `int` to make this function work for as big numbers as possible.)

Comment: It may return `bool` instead of `int`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now it works regular. But I'm still not clear about why my code works regular on CB 10.05 and does not work on CB 12.11, 13.12? Might it be about compiler which @chris commented above, or might be another reason?

Comment: @Bilal Again, `pow()` and/or other stuff. It's really time you fire up your debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on the comment thread between myself and H2CO3, I offer here the comparison between the string method and number method of checking for palindromes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

int ispal(unsigned long long n)
{
    unsigned long long o = n;
    unsigned long long k = 0;
    while (n) {
        k *= 10;
        k += n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }

    return o == k;
}

int ispalc(char* s)
{
    char *e;
    e = s + strlen(s) - 1;
    while(s < e)
    {
      if( *s++ != *e-- ) return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(void) {
    unsigned long long num;
    int ii;
    time_t startT, endT, diff1, diff2;
    char nums[128];

    std::cout<<"Enter a number : ";
    std::cin>>num;

    if (ispal(num) != 0) std::cout << "It is a palindrome" << std::endl;
    else std::cout << "It is not a palindrome" << std::endl;

    sprintf(nums, "%lld", num);

    if (ispalc(nums) != 0) std::cout << "It is a palindrome" << std::endl;
    else std::cout << "It is not a palindrome" << std::endl;
    startT = clock();
    for(ii = 0; ii < 1000000; ii++) ispal(num);
    endT = clock();
    diff1 = (endT - startT);

    startT = clock();
    for(ii = 0; ii < 1000000; ii++) ispalc(num);
    endT = clock();
    diff2 = (endT - startT);

    printf("using numbers: %.2lf us\n", diff1 * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC );
    printf("using strings: %.2lf us\n", diff2 * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC );
    return 0;
}
```

Couple of things to notice:

1. I left the conversion of string to number and number to string outside of the timing loop. Since the user input is in fact a string (that gets converted to a number), that gives the number method an advantage. In "real life", the conversion of string to number would be one of the slower operations in this whole thing.
2. I made the type of the number `unsigned long long` at the main level as well; and also the type of `o` inside the function (it was `unsigned long`). This made the code slightly faster as it did not spend time doing conversions.

Drum roll… with the above caveats, the timing performance was:

```
Enter a number : 123454321
It is a palindrome
It is a palindrome
using numbers: 68.51 us
using strings: 26.27 us

Enter a number : 1234567
It is not a palindrome
It is not a palindrome
using numbers: 53.03 us
using strings: 11.78 us
```

The winner seems clear to me - "the strings have it".